# How to get package name using blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am new to blackberry development, Is it possible to get package name of the application which is installed in device. I din't get any reference for this.

```
 int[] handle = codeModuleManager.getModuleHandles();                    
        for(int i=0; i<handle.length; i++){  
            ApplicationDescriptor[] app_descriptors = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(handle[i]);               
                if(app_descriptors != null){ 
                    System.out.println("app_descriptors length "+ app_descriptors.length);   
                    for(int j=0; j< app_descriptors.length; j++){
                        System.out.println("Iterating the arraylist :: "+ app_descriptors[j].toString());
                    } 
                }               
        }
```

Comment: int m_bbHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("your module name"); check the module is available or not.

Comment: Thanks, i want to get all package name, not only one specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -
This will get all the installed modules.

```
int[] v=net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandles();
```

For getting the ApplicationDescriptors associated with the module, use the following code -

```
net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(int moduleHandle)
```

**Edit : -**

```
int[] handle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandles();                    
    for(int i=0; i<handle.length; i++){  
        ApplicationDescriptor[] app_descriptors = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(handle[i]);               
            if(app_descriptors != null){ 
                System.out.println("app_descriptors length "+ app_descriptors.length);   
                for(int j=0; j< app_descriptors.length; j++){
                     String moduleName = app_descriptors[i].getModuleName();
                     String name = app_descriptors[i].getName();


                } 
            }               
    }
```

Comment: Thanks again,I get the following when I try to print the app_descriptor

Comment: sorry, net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor@3e3f45f

Comment: use a for loop and print the values in the array v.

Comment: yes, i used for loop, but i am getting like net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor@3e3f45f. For every time complete the loop this kind of result iam getting, but i din't get any package name. can you pls guide me how to solve this.

Comment: Is there any one to help me regarding this?

Comment: Thanks, I can able to get the application name which where installed in the device. but i need to get package name like (com.example.example). Is this possible in blackberry .